# How to run a Java application as Windows service using WinRun4J

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, winrun4j

I'm trying to run a Java application as a Windows service with WinRun4J.

I copied WinRun4J64c.exe in my application directory and placed the following service.ini file beside:

```
service.class=org.boris.winrun4j.MainService
service.id=MyAPP
service.name=MyAPP
service.description=some description

classpath.1=./lib/*
classpath.2=WinRun4J.jar

[MainService]
class=play.core.server.NettyServer
```

But if I start the service with: `WinRun4J64c.exe --WinRun4J:RegisterService` I get:

```
Service control dispatcher error: 1063
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get it working, so my workaround is to use [Apache Commons Deamon](http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/). I executed the included prunsrv.exe with the following parameters:

```
prunsrv.exe install "MeineAnwendung" \
--Install="C:/pfad/zu/prunsrv.exe" \
--JvmOptions=-Dpidfile.path=NUL
--Jvm=auto \
--Startup=auto \
--StartMode=jvm \
--Classpath="c:/irgendwo/anwendung/lib/*;" \
--StartClass=play.core.server.NettyServer
```